# Python subprocess does not work

Tags: python, subprocess

I try to use a program called bwa in python with the subprocess module:
subprocess.call('bwa', shell=True)
Result is:
/bin/sh: bwa: command not found
However if I start a terminal and type the command, the program starts (i.e. I get the Usage dialogue).

The binaries of bwa are in a folder on my desktop. In .bash_profile I have modified the path variable so that everytime I type 'bwa' in the terminal, the program binaries are found in my folder.

My assumption is that the subprocess does not start a shell with my bash_profile settings ... but if that is correct why wouldn't it do so and what can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried replace your `subprocess.call` command `bwa` to absolute path of where the binary is? i.e. `/path/to/your/bwa`

Comment: Well if I do it like subprocess.call('~/Desktop/Programs/bwa-0.7.12/bwa', shell=True) then it works. But that's not really a solution since I want the program to work on other computers that have installed bwa ...

Comment: I mean if I just write a shell script and put 'bwa' in it, then this shell script works on any system where I can call bwa from a terminal. I want the same in python, how to achieve this?

Comment: if you know you're going to place the `bwa` file along your script, you can call with `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'bwa')`...

Comment: At the moment I am trying this, but it gives me an error message (arg 3 must be a mapping object): my_env = os.environ
my_env = my_env["PATH"]
subprocess.call('bwa', env=my_env, shell=True)

Comment: 1. Are you sure `.bash_profile` is read? What do you see if you run `python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["PATH"])'`? 2. Don't put additional questions in the comments; update your question instead (there is an "edit" button under it).